# Adding !one! entity to my game adds !two! entities

Tags: java, file, jframe, addition

My question is:
Why does adding an entity to my game (`entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 19 * 64, 7 * 64));`) add 2 entities at once?
I added 8 new trees, and got 12, so I was confused.
On top of that, I have a world.txt file that has my whole world's tiles in it.
The world class is here:

```
public class World {

    private Handler handler;
    private int width, height;
    private int spawnX, spawnY;
    private int[][] tiles;
    //Entities
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public World(Handler handler, String path){
        this.handler = handler;
        entityManager = new EntityManager(handler, new Player(handler, 100, 100));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 16 * 64, 7 * 64));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 17 * 64, 7 * 64));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 18 * 64, 7 * 64));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 19 * 64, 7 * 64));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 16 * 64, 6 * 64));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 17 * 64, 6 * 64));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 18 * 64, 6 * 64));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 19 * 64, 6 * 64));
        entityManager.addEntity(new Rock(handler, 100, 450));

        loadWorld(path);

        entityManager.getPlayer().setX(spawnX);
        entityManager.getPlayer().setY(spawnY);
    }

    public void tick(){
        entityManager.tick();
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        int xStart = (int) Math.max(0, handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset() / Tile.TILEWIDTH);
        int xEnd = (int) Math.min(width, (handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset() + handler.getWidth()) / Tile.TILEWIDTH + 1);
        int yStart = (int) Math.max(0, handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset() / Tile.TILEHEIGHT);
        int yEnd = (int) Math.min(height, (handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset() + handler.getHeight()) / Tile.TILEHEIGHT + 1);

        for(int y = yStart;y < yEnd;y++){
            for(int x = xStart;x < xEnd;x++){
                getTile(x, y).render(g, (int) (x * Tile.TILEWIDTH - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()),
                        (int) (y * Tile.TILEHEIGHT - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()));
            }
        }
        //Entities
        entityManager.render(g);
    }

    public Tile getTile(int x, int y){
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= width || y >= height)
            return Tile.grassTile;

        Tile t = Tile.tiles[tiles[x][y]];
        if(t == null)
            return Tile.dirtTile;
        return t;
    }

    private void loadWorld(String path){
        String file = Utils.loadFileAsString(path);
        String[] tokens = file.split("\\s+");
        width = Utils.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        height = Utils.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        spawnX = Utils.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        spawnY = Utils.parseInt(tokens[3]);

        tiles = new int[width][height];
        for(int y = 0;y < height;y++){
            for(int x = 0;x < width;x++){
                tiles[x][y] = Utils.parseInt(tokens[(x + y * width) + 4]);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

My EntityManager class is here:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

import dev.blaze.tilegame.Handler;
import dev.blaze.tilegame.entity.creatures.*;

public class EntityManager {

    private Handler handler;
    private Player player;
    private ArrayList<Entity> entities;
    private Comparator<Entity> renderSorter = new Comparator<Entity>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Entity a, Entity b) {
            if(a.getY() + a.getHeight() < b.getY() + b.getHeight())
                return -1;
            return 1;
        }
    };

    public EntityManager(Handler handler, Player player){
        this.handler = handler;
        this.player = player;
        entities = new ArrayList<Entity>();
        addEntity(player);
    }

    public void tick(){
        for(int i = 0;i < entities.size();i++){
            Entity e = entities.get(i);
            e.tick();
            if(!e.isActive())
                entities.remove(e);
        }
        entities.sort(renderSorter);
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        for(Entity e : entities){
            e.render(g);
        }
    }

    public void addEntity(Entity e){
        entities.add(e);
    }

    //GETTERS SETTERS

    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }

    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public ArrayList<Entity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(ArrayList<Entity> entities) {
        this.entities = entities;
    }

}
```

I don't think the error is in the EntityManager class, it might be where I made the Tree class, or just eclipse's error.
The tree class is here:

```
    public class Tree extends StaticEntity {

    public Tree(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
        super(handler, x, y, Tile.TILEWIDTH, Tile.TILEHEIGHT * 2);

        bounds.x = 0;
        bounds.y = 0;
        bounds.width = width;
        bounds.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {

    }

    @Override
    public void die(){

    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(Assets.log, (int) (x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()), width, height, null);
    }

}
```

If you need to know any other classes, tell me in the comments.

Comment: well let's see that EntityManager class too at least. Also what exactly is giving you the hint that this method adds too many items. Debugger view of memory? output of some function?

Comment: The hint that I'm getting is that when I mine the block, it mines two blocks and it covers three tiles and not two. All the tiles are a size of two tiles, they're just overlapping, giving three and not four. @BrunoDelor

Comment: I don't see anything that would result in duplication of entities. Use the debug feature of your IDE to check the state of your program when it runs. if your list only contains the entities you need this means that the mistake is more toward the code managing mining

Comment: @BrunoDelor could it be in the Tree class where I set tree to draw itself? I added the tree class so you could have a look, and debug isn't helping since I have like 20 classes

Comment: it could indeed. It's a bit of a prediction exercice for me right now but my bets are either on the code that calculate what is getting interracted with in the world or the code drawing a single entity. Maybe try with one tree and see if a second one appears if yes then initialize it elsewhere and see if the other one move in the same way

Comment: Debug always help, you just need to think more about where to put your breakpoints :3

Comment: @BrunoDelor It's with the `entityManager.addEntity(new Tree(handler, 19 * 64, 7 * 64));`.

Comment: I know, just add only one tree or one rock and check if you see multiple ones instead. if yes then it is a strong indicator that it is drawing wrong. if not then it's a stong indicator that it is your interaction algorithm that is not doing it's job

Comment: @BrunoDelor I did, that's how I knew it was duplicating.

Comment: My bad, would you mind uploading your project so I can attempt replicating your results?

Comment: @BrunoDelor one sec, let me get all of the classes into a github repo

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/CodeNMore/New-Beginner-Java-Game-Programming-Src/tree/master/Episode%2031/TileGame, every class is in it, though a few need spritesheets made in paint.net. Just warning you: this isn't my code, it's a youtuber's code that I used to make my own game, the codes are very similar, though.

Comment: is that your code? it looks like a tutorial repository; if you have changed anything from this code I cannot really rely on it. on the other hand if it is the base code itself that have problem I might notice somthing; but it will not be as easy as using directly your version

Comment: @BrunoDelor it is, I customized it to be what I want, but that is the code.

Comment: you meant the code from episode 32 right? I've been checking episode 31 but no code to kill a tree or a rock. Unless you coded these parts yourself?

Comment: you really should put all your code online somewhere it will be easier

Comment: @BrunoDelor no, 31, look in the tree, rock, and player classes. Ep 31 is the episode where you attack entities.

Comment: yeah, and the code in githhub for episode 31 doesn't contain any code to handle death of an entity. I have the code under my eyes. All of the episodes' code. Also seeing your answer it indeed was a problem I couldn't find without your project as the problem relied in how the code was interacted with your assets. In any cases I'm glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tree class, instead of putting width and height, I replaced both with 64 and got only one tree / log instead of two.
Instead of:

```
g.drawImage(Assets.log, (int) (x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()), width, height, null);
```

it was:

```
g.drawImage(Assets.log, (int) (x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()), 64, 64, null);
```